# How can I download Xamarin Studio 4.2 ? Is it still supported?

Tags: macos, download, xamarin

I have a mac book pro with Mac OS x 10.8.4 and xamarin studio's new vesions do not support this OS .(I need at least 10.9)

I searched on the web for links but I did not find any.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Do you need Xamarin Studio (for mobile devel) or just MonoDevelop at that version?

Comment: Needed for Android development :)

Comment: You should be able to get it from Xamarin in your acct's downloads section: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads

Comment: 4.2 Is not presented on the download site ! Only back to 5.9.4!

Comment: Email Xamarin's support for a direct download link with the reason you need that version...

Answer (score 0):

Currently theres no Developer Environment out there for your OS X Version. 
But Android Studio is OS X 10.8.5 ready. If you have 10.8.4, you're able to download 10.8.5.

Currently, there are no other ways to download and Android Environment. 
Link to Android Studio by Google: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I hope, i've helped you

Greetings Dominic

Comment: No, it won't. Either you download 10.11 (El Capitan), or you can download windows and run Visual Studio in a virtual box (C# for android is possible).